# How to ignore error and continue with the Loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I get runtime errror 53: file not found for the 27th-28th item. Any idea what is wrong?

The error lies with:

"FileCopy Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestinationPath"

```
Option Base 1
Sub LoopThroughFolder()

    Const FileSpec As String = "*.xls"
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim iDot As Integer
    Dim FileRoot As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    Dim SourcePath As String
    Dim DestinationPath As String

    Dim ArrayData() As Variant
    Dim Series() As Integer


    'Capture the filename information
    For y = 2009 To 2030
        ReDim Preserve ArrayData(12, y)
        ReDim Preserve Series(12, y)
        MyFolder = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & y & "\"

        i = 1
        MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & FileSpec)
        Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
            iDot = InStrRev(MyFile, ".")

            If iDot = 0 Then
                FileRoot = MyFile
                FileExt = ""
            Else
                FileRoot = Left(MyFile, iDot - 1)
                FileExt = Mid(MyFile, iDot - 1)
            End If

            MyFile = Dir
            ArrayData(i, y) = FileRoot
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next y

    'Conversion from MMMYY to numerical sequence
    a = 1
    BasicPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    For y = 2009 To 2030
        For i = 1 To 12
            If Not IsEmpty(ArrayData(i, y)) Then
                Series(i, y) = a
                a = a + 1

                SourcePath = BasicPath & "\" & y & "\" & ArrayData(i, y) & ".xls"
                DestinationPath = BasicPath & "\output\" & "Bill_Summary_Report_" & Series(i, y) & ".xls"

                FileCopy Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestinationPath

            Else
                x = 0
            End If
        Next i
    Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: What was your question, really? _'Why do I get an error?'_ or _'Oh well, I don't care what it is; how do I skip it?'_ Those are two very different things, yet your title says one, and your post says another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Sub LoopThroughFolder()
  on error resume next
  .....
```

Comment: @TingPing That's the right question: what is the cause for the error. This code literally just ignores the error and continues. Probably not what you want. It's like sticking your head in the sand and pretending the sky is not falling around you. [The documentation for FileCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s1c774y.aspx) gives you a list of things that can go wrong and cause the function to fail. Most likely, it's an `IOException` indicating that the file is currently open/in use and cannot be copied.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a function **fileExist** which will true if path exist. Before this line "FileCopy Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestinationPath" is called it always better to checkif they exist and if yes then proceed with filecopy.

Option Base 1
    Sub LoopThroughFolder()

```
    Const FileSpec As String = "*.xlsm"
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim iDot As Integer
    Dim FileRoot As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    Dim SourcePath As String
    Dim DestinationPath As String

    Dim ArrayData() As Variant
    Dim Series() As Integer


    'Capture the filename information
    For y = 2009 To 2030
        ReDim Preserve ArrayData(12, y)
        ReDim Preserve Series(12, y)
        MyFolder = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & y & "\"

        i = 1
        MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & FileSpec)
        Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
            iDot = InStrRev(MyFile, ".")

            If iDot = 0 Then
                FileRoot = MyFile
                FileExt = ""
            Else
                FileRoot = Left(MyFile, iDot - 1)
                FileExt = Mid(MyFile, iDot - 1)
            End If

            MyFile = Dir
            ArrayData(i, y) = FileRoot
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    Next y

    'Conversion from MMMYY to numerical sequence
    a = 1
    BasicPath = ActiveWorkbook.path
    For y = 2009 To 2030
        For i = 1 To 12
            If Not IsEmpty(ArrayData(i, y)) Then
                Series(i, y) = a
                a = a + 1

                SourcePath = BasicPath & "\" & y & "\" & ArrayData(i, y) & ".xls"
                DestinationPath = BasicPath & "\output\" & "Bill_Summary_Report_" & Series(i, y) & ".xls"

                If fileExist(SourcePath) And fileExist(DestinationPath) Then
                    FileCopy Source:=SourcePath, Destination:=DestinationPath
                End If

            Else
                x = 0
            End If
        Next i
    Next y

End Sub

Function fileExist(path As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim file As String
    file = Dir(path)

    If file <> "" Then fileExist = True

    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: What have you changed here? Why does it fix the problem? We shouldn't have to diff the code ourselves to find out. (Although I did, and your code suffers from a race condition. Checking the existence of a file before you perform file IO is essentially useless; the file can disappear between the time you perform the check and the time you execute the IO operation. You just need to handle the errors.)

Comment: Checking the existence of a file before you perform file IO is essentially useless. Why do you think so?

Comment: I explained this. It suffers from a race condition. The file can disappear between the time you perform the check and the time you execute the IO operation. That would cause the IO operation to fail, just as if you hadn't bothered to check.

Comment: the file can disappear ... is there any magic . Do you know the enviornment of OP?

Comment: It doesn't require magic or any special knowledge of the environment. It just requires someone deleting the file. Obviously you think it's possible the file might not exist, or you wouldn't bother to call `fileExists`.

Comment: How much milli seconds would it take before it would do filecopy? any guess ??

Comment: It's irrelevant. You've already agreed it's possible, now it's just a matter of likelihood. That's the whole point of a race condition. It *might* work, it might *usually* work, but it also might blow up. That's bad design. It's better to just handle the error in the first place and omit the redundant check, since you're going to have to handle error conditions anyway. (And it's not really as uncommon as it seems in practice. Consider the case where you're accessing a file on the network and someone unplugs the network cable.)

Comment: That is what i said dont assume. Do you know the envoirnment of the OP ?

Comment: There is nothing here that requires any assumptions. I gave you an *example* at the very end, and there are a thousand other possible examples. Don't miss the larger point.

Comment: Its easier to comment. Thanks